# How to create empty measurement in influx

Tags: influxdb

Insert cpu,host=tools value=10
This creates a measurement with field and tag but how to create empty measurement

Answer (score 0):

In INFLUX DB , you cant create empty measurements. You need to add some data since influx db work on dynamically creating the columns therefore you have define the values.